# How to serialize a List with JAXB and XmlJavaTypeAdapter?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a `List<String>` that I want to serialize using `JAXB`. The list is also preprocessed by some `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` as follows:

```
@XmlElement(name = "category")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdapterXml.class) //for modifying some values inside the list during serialization
private List<String> categories;
```

Result:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB cannot process interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.List
```

Why? How can I serialize the list?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `AdapterXml<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>` instead of implementing just the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use annotation @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdapterXml.class). Try with below

```
@XmlElement(name = "category")
//for modifying some values inside the no need any special type of annotation.
list during serialization
private List<String> categories;
```

Comment: I do need the `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to transform values inside the list (add a suffix and postfix to each string in the list). So I *cannot* remove it!